WebOS 6.0 Signage "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED" with a Flutter web app IPK
After compiling a flutter application into a web app, creating a appinfo.json file, packaging the application as a IPK, and loading it to a webOS 6.0 Signage monitor, I get the error:
flutter.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

WebOS specs:

modelName : 32SM5J-BP
sdkVersion : 6.0.0
firmwareVersion : 06.05.91
boardType : M16P3_ATSC_US
otaId : HE_IDD_S21H_DSAAGLAA

Steps to reproduce:
create a new flutter project: flutter create sample_project
build the flutter project: flutter build web
in the build/web directory: create a appinfo.json. This is my contents:
{
    "id": "com.lg.app.signage",
    "title": "AppName",
    "main": "index.html",
    "type": "web",
    "icon": "favicon.png",
    "vendor": "My Company",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "appDescription": "This is an app tagline",
    "resolution": "1920x1080",
    "iconColor": "red",
    "transparent": false,
    "requiredMemory": 20,
    "requiredPermissions": ["time.query", "media.operation", "activity.operation"],
    "inspectable": true
}

build the IPK: ares-package --no-minify .
upload the IPK to webOS.
I was expecting the web app to work as a IPK, as it runs fine on my browser and webOS6.0 uses Chromium 79
